# Insert all data of a datagridview to database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have a datagridview which is created by various action and user's manipulation of data. I want to insert all the data of the gridview to the database at once, I know I could try a code similar to this:

```
private void btnSaveProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = DBConnectivity.getConnection();
    if (connection != null)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dGvProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO product (productName) " + "VALUES (@productName)";
                SqlCommand command = DBConnectivity.getCommandForQuery(query, connection);
                    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(result + "");
            }
            //  string query = "Insert into units(name,packing)values('" + txtNameUnit.Text + "' , '" + txtPackingUnit.Text + "')";
            //  SqlCommand command = DBConnectivity.getCommandForQuery(query, connection);
            //  int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //  Console.WriteLine(result + "");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();    
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: sir write this code but unable to insert values in database table

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: what is the `result` of executenonquery? could you write out the exception message in your catch block?

Comment: Is your connection opened?

Comment: To understand what really happens here you should remove that empty catch block. You are effectively swallowing the exception and you cannot know what error do you get. I could clearly see a missing parameter there but let see the exact error message.

Comment: The code is incomplete. You don't even read the value from the grid view, much less pass it to the command.

Answer (score 0):

As is, the code tries to execute a parameterized query but never assigns a value to the parameter. Even if you do, you never extract the cell values.

The code should look like this:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO product (productName) VALUES (@productName)";

using var(connection = DBConnectivity.getConnection())
using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    var productParam=command.Parameters.Add("@productName",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50);

    connection.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dGvProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
    {                    
        var productName=dGvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[somecolumn].Value;
        productParam.Value=productName;
        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }       
}
```